# Different header for mobile

Tags: css, html

Doing a static site for a client and they want to have a totally different main menu design for mobile devices (more of a App look and feel).

What is the best way to serve this? Having two header tags, one for desktop and one for mobile?

**This is what I have now:**

```
<header class="desktop-only-header">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>

<header class="mobile-only-header">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/"><i class="icon-home"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="/about"><i class="icon-about"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact"><i class="icon-contact"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="/best-articles"><i class="icon-best-articles"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-social"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

I tried to have only one header but the amount of CSS needed to change the look and feel (show and hide content) on mobile was just too much.

Comment: use media queries to show/hide header section based on device

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I detect mobile devices (and/or mobile cookie) without scripting (PHP) or server configuration (Nginx)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496118/how-can-i-detect-mobile-devices-and-or-mobile-cookie-without-scripting-php-o)

Comment: Responsive Design FTW! Using RD you can use the same HTML markup, and hide/show the necessary nav items on the mobile/desktop layouts, and even change the layout. As @RahulB commented, you'll use `@media` queries to accomplish this.

Comment: From a semantic web point of view, this would be bad practise and it is advisable to do it all in CSS. If you do it your way you'll confuse search engines and screenreaders. It can't be that bad. Perhaps it's better to tell us what you are trying to achieve - what the actual differences are.

Comment: @BramVanroy I see what you mean in regards to search engines. Since I have little reputation points I can't post an image of what I want to achieve. The desktop version in regards to design and menu items is less than the mobile version, also the logo on the desktop version is also different.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [mediaqueries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to show and hide different content depending on screensize.

So for example:

```
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (max-width: 768px) { 
  #header_desktop{
   display:none;
  }
  #header_mobile{
   display:initial;
  }
}
```

The above code will hide the desktop nav and show the mobile nav when the screen width drops below 768px. Make sure you hide the mobile nav in general.

```css
.mobile-only-header {
  display: none;
}


/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .desktop-only-header {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile-only-header {
    display: initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="desktop-only-header">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Desktop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>

<header class="mobile-only-header">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</i></a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks for that! But in regards to the "correct way" of doing it, not seen that many sites with a mobile header and a desktop header.

Comment: Of course having 1 header is better. Like @BramVanroy said. But your question is how to hide/show different headers on mobile. The above is a solution to that question.

Answer (score 1):

to design a different view for mobile from desktop, you can easily write neccessary code into media query tag in CSS. but first design for mobile, then design for desktop; because in modern days, all responsive site maintains mobile-first design thereafter desktop design. And you can use your style like:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
 //your code for desktop view
}
```

I hope my suggestion will help you.